# Ruby on Rails : Find all departmentid from Users Table

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I have Users Table which contains many fields including departmentid. departmentid is just a string . Each departmentid can have different users.Is it possible to find all departmentid from Users table without repetation.

I tried to find all departmentid from users table ,but the result contains duplication of departmentid.How to solve this .

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SQL

```
select distinct department_id from users
```

Ruby code

```
User.all.map(&:department_id).compact.uniq
```

also in rails 3

```
User.select('departement_id').uniq
```

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to use a sql query to let the db engine to handle the math and avoid creating ruby objects, its the faster option:

```
Department.where("id in (select distinct department_id from users)").all
```

Now if you want to do it the rails way, you can still do:

```
Department.where(id: User.select("distinct department_id").map(&:department_id)).all
```

Notice that with this last line of code, you avoid creating a complete mapping of the User attributes, since all you are interested in is the department_id, and also it avoids going though every User object in order to collect the ids and make them uniq, by using select distinct the database engine will just return the single values without repetition

Comment: Btw `User.select('email').uniq.to_sql` gives in rails3
 `=> "SELECT DISTINCT email FROM users " `